# How to determine the DC that ADsOpenObject is bound to?

Tags: c++, c, active-directory, adsi, domaincontroller

I have a service that receives an **ADsPath** to a container. For e.g.

> LDAP://CN=Users,DC-=Contaso,DC=com

I call `ADsOpenObject()` using this path and create a user object. I need to return the name of the domain controller that was used in the bind in order to allow the caller to reopen the same DC (otherwise the caller may not find the new object if a different DC is used before replication completes)

Answer (score 0):

You can use the DsGetDcName() function returns the name of a domain controller in a specified domain.

DSGETDCAPI DWORD DsGetDcNameA(
  IN LPCSTR                    ComputerName,
  IN LPCSTR                    DomainName,
  IN GUID                      *DomainGuid,
  IN LPCSTR                    SiteName,
  IN ULONG                     Flags,
  OUT PDOMAIN_CONTROLLER_INFOA *DomainControllerInfo
);
Please refer to microsoft doc here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/api/dsgetdc/nf-dsgetdc-dsgetdcnamea